# Access VBA Replace function returning values from Replace string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use the REPLACE function to search a string and remove a charcter. Here is the code..

```
SELECT Test.*, Replace([Data],ChrW(10),"",(Len([Data])-2),1) FROM Test;
```

Although this is just a select stmt, the result set returns the last three characters of data from the column [Data]. Instead of starting the search in that location.

The UPDATE statement here, does the same...

```
 UPDATE Test SET Test.Data = Replace([Data],ChrW(10),"",(LEN([Data])-2)) 
 WHERE (((Test.[Data]) Like ("*" & ChrW(10))));
```

I would still expect the search to being at the results of LEN([Data])-2. Instead only the last characters are returned. The substitution is successful.

Any help on my oversight here would be appreciated.

Comment: The [start] and [count] parameters are optional. Does it work correctly if you leave those out? i.e. `Replace([Data],ChrW(10),"")`

Comment: Yes it does, but I risk removing all of the chrW(10) from the string which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird. I have confirmed what you're getting. In a query, adding a starting position to the Replace() function acts as a Right() function as well. I can't find any documentation for that. In VBA, it behaves as one would expect, in that it returns the whole string, sans the replaced chars.

You have 3 options for a workaround.

1. You can replace all Chrw(10), but I think you probably don't want to do that since you specified a start position.
2. You can use the IIF() statement to test if the last char is Chr(10), and if so, do a Left() function to exclude the last char. Kinda messy.
3. If you're working in Access, you can create your own function in VBA and call it instead. You can call your function Repl, so it would look something like this: **UPDATE Test SET Test.Data = Repl([Data])**.

Comment: Also, be aware that a lot of times, a Chr(10) [line feed] is preceded by a Chr(13) [carriage return]. I have also seen Chr(13) used by itself. Just something to look out for.